# Need to create Linux Users from Windows Machine using Batch file or Script . I am having ssh access to server.

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having several Linux machine in my DC and i need to create one script in Windows Server which will create users on Linux machines. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have OpenSSH installed, just run this in your batch file once per linux client:

```
ssh root@linux-machine "adduser user_name --home /home/user_name"
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, I am already having the script in my linux machine. It will read values and create user. Lot of options i have included. i found plinks with -t option. Let me try  :) Thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a look to [expect for Windows](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/expect4win/). Like the Unix version, you can remotely execute interactive commands.